# replace a character in a string using index c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

I just start to learn c++/cli, please help.
How do i convert string '----' to string like 'A-C-' if only the 0 and second character in the string meet the condition.

```
char str[] = "-----";
if // 0 true
{str[0] = "A";}
if // 1 true
{str[1] = "B";}
if // 2 true
{str[2] = "C";}
if // 3 true
{str[3] = "D";}
```

Comment: If you're already using C++/CLI, why not use the managed System::String class to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the .Net `StringBuilder` class you can replace a char in a string at a give index :

```
StringBuilder ^sb = gcnew StringBuilder(myString);
sb[index] = myChar;
myString = sb->ToString();
```